# Объединение списков по определенному алгоритму

Tags: c#, .net

Есть несколько списков List<*string>*. Колл-во списков может быть разным.

Примерная архитектура списков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сгруппировать списки таким образом, чтобы получить единый список по такому алгоритму **без рекурсии** и желательно без *Linq*:

```
Item1-Item2-Item3-Item4-Item5
Item1-Item2-Item3-Item4-Item55
Item1-Item2-Item3-Item4-Item555

Item1-Item2-Item3-Item44-Item5
Item1-Item2-Item3-Item44-Item55
Item1-Item2-Item3-Item44-Item555

Item1-Item22-Item3-Item4-Item5
Item1-Item22-Item3-Item4-Item55
Item1-Item22-Item3-Item4-Item555

Item1-Item22-Item3-Item44-Item5
Item1-Item22-Item3-Item44-Item55
Item1-Item22-Item3-Item44-Item555

Item1-Item222-Item3-Item4-Item5
Item1-Item222-Item3-Item4-Item55
Item1-Item222-Item3-Item4-Item555

Item1-Item222-Item3-Item44-Item5
Item1-Item222-Item3-Item44-Item55
Item1-Item222-Item3-Item44-Item555

Item11-Item2-Item3-Item4-Item5
Item11-Item2-Item3-Item4-Item55
Item11-Item2-Item3-Item4-Item555

Item11-Item2-Item3-Item44-Item5
Item11-Item2-Item3-Item44-Item55
Item11-Item2-Item3-Item44-Item555

Item11-Item22-Item3-Item4-Item5
Item11-Item22-Item3-Item4-Item55
Item11-Item22-Item3-Item4-Item555

Item11-Item22-Item3-Item44-Item5
Item11-Item22-Item3-Item44-Item55
Item11-Item22-Item3-Item44-Item555

Item11-Item222-Item3-Item4-Item5
Item11-Item222-Item3-Item4-Item55
Item11-Item222-Item3-Item4-Item555

Item11-Item222-Item3-Item44-Item5
Item11-Item222-Item3-Item44-Item55
Item11-Item222-Item3-Item44-Item555
```

Подскажите реализацию или хоть с какой стороны подойти к задаче.

Comment: По какому алгоритму?

Comment: То есть вы желаете получить все варианты, где первый элемент выбирается из первого списка, второй - из второго и т.д.?

Comment: Строка должна объединять элементы всех списков. Разность элементов должна начинаться с последнего списка и идти к первому. Поэтому привел пример. Пример - разбил по элементам для наглядности, это все результат выполнения метода, весь результат.

Comment: @EzikBro, да, разность элементов начинается с последнего списка и идет к первому.

Comment: Элементарный перебор. Вложенные циклы по количеству списков.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, колл-во списков может быть разным. Можете привести пример? Не обязательно точный, просто код, который даст направление для реализации уже под эту задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ежели рекурсия вам неугодна, то адекватным является такой вариант:

```
List<List<string>> vars = new List<List<string>> {
                new List<string> { "1", "11" },
                new List<string> { "2", "22", "222" },
                new List<string> { "3" },
                new List<string> { "4", "44" },
                new List<string> { "5", "55", "555" }
            };

List<int> varsSize = new List<int>(vars.Count);
int countOfCombinations = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < vars.Count; i++)
{
    varsSize.Add(vars[i].Count);
    countOfCombinations *= vars[i].Count;
}

List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();
for (int comb = 0; comb < countOfCombinations; comb++)
{
    int tmp = comb;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = vars.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        list.Add(vars[i][tmp % varsSize[i]]);
        tmp /= varsSize[i];
    }
    list.Reverse();
    result.Add(list);
}

foreach (List<string> comb in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("-", comb));
}
```

Это работает по принципу смешанной позиционной системы счисления, где для каждого разряда задано количество используемых в нем цифр.

Comment: Благодарю, очень интересная реализация.